# How can I change the taxonomy term title?

Tags: 8, taxonomy-terms

Simple as that. I want to change the H1 tag from taxonomy views to something like "Articles from %term" to make it more user friendly and not redundant (breadcrumbs shows the term *alone*).

I couldn't find that information in the template or in taxonomy views options.

Comment: Is it not part of the contextual argument options?

Comment: I thought the same thing but I could not modify the title from that options. If I change text to test in {{ arguments.tid }} argument options, i didn't see that changes in pages -cleaning all caches-.

Answer (score 0):

The `Title` for the `Taxonomy term` Views is set to `None`, so using the `Override title` from the Contextual filters won't display.

The `<h1>` on that Views actually comes from the `Header` option:  **Global: Rendered entity - Taxonomy term (Global: Rendered entity - Taxonomy term)**.

That is where you need to change it:

[image: Header Taxonomy term names Page Title]

Comment: Tried changing that view mode, clearing al caches and it didn't work: https://i.ibb.co/P5zKpCk/taxonomy-title.png

Title for Taxonomy View is set to None; same override is applied to Contextual Filters. I'm not using taxonomy twig templates.

Comment: Do you have the two checkboxes checked, especially the one to use tokens from the first row? It's difficult to say why it's not working for you, it should if you have only changed the recommended options. You don't need to clear cache to be able to see the changes, you can use Views Preview to check it. Try Bartik theme just to rule out that it's the theme causing it.

Comment: I have the two checkboxes checked and I've changed the options as you showed before.

I tried in Bartik with the same result. Do you have an idea that what can be wrong with this?